# Transforming table with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

not much experience with Pandas, searched the threads but could not find something similar.

I have large 1mil records table with following structure,

```
+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+
|  rec  | code  | code group  | code Date |
+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| 10001 | X11   | High        | 20151105  |
| 10001 | X11.1 | High        | 20150205  |
| 10001 | X12   | Medium      | 20141111  |
| 10001 | X12.1 | Medium      | 20141111  |
| 10001 | X13   | Low         | 20130101  |
| 10001 | Y15   | No Interest | 20130101  |
| 10001 | Y16   | No Interest | 20141231  |
| 10002 | X11   | …           | …         |
| 10002 | X12   | …           | …         |
| 10002 | X13   | …           | …         |
+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+
```

and would like to structure it into the table were only unique rec will reside and in following format:

Header:
rec|High (largest date)|Medium (largest date)|Low (largest date)|Code (of H Only with largest date)|    High Code (Count)

Comment: Please format your tables into something understandable by viewing the question. I did this for your input, but can't do it for the output.

Comment: sorry that was first cur...forgot about tables. thanx

Comment: The expected result is still not clear (High Code (largest date)). Could you give us a row example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some clues.

```
# Test data
df = DataFrame({'rec': [10001, 10001, 10002, 10002],
 'code': ['X11', 'X12', 'X11.1', 'X12'],
 'code group': ['High', 'High', 'High', 'Medium'],
 'code Date': ['20151105', '20141111', '20151004', '20151004']
}, columns = ['rec', 'code', 'code group', 'code Date'])

# Converting dates
df['code Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['code Date'])

#      rec   code code group  code Date
# 0  10001    X11       High 2015-11-05
# 1  10001    X12       High 2014-11-11
# 2  10002  X11.1       High 2015-10-04
# 3  10002    X12     Medium 2015-10-04
```

This how to get "rec, High (largest date), Medium (largest date), Low (largest date)"

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, 
               index = 'rec', 
               columns='code group', 
               values='code Date', 
               aggfunc='max')

# code group       High     Medium
# rec                             
# 10001      2015-11-05        NaT
# 10002      2015-10-04 2015-10-04
```

This how to get the code with the highest date and the count of the number of rows.

```
# Filterting and sorting the values in order to have last dates first
filt = df[df['code group'] == 'High'].sort_values(['rec', 'code Date'], ascending=[True, False])
# Keeping the first value for code (the one with last date), and counting the rows
filt = filt.groupby('rec').agg({'code': 'first', 'code Date': 'size'})

#        code Date   code
# rec                    
# 10001          2    X11
# 10002          1  X11.1
```

Assembling data to get the final result.

```
pivot.join(filt).rename(columns={'code Date': 'count'})

# code group       High     Medium  count   code
# rec                                           
# 10001      2015-11-05        NaT      2    X11
# 10002      2015-10-04 2015-10-04      1  X11.1
```

Comment: Thanx for the comment, sorry on the formatting issue of the results table. I have also reached first part of the code but wanted to transpose code group into the header and with largest date recorded

Comment: Thanx for the pivot,two 10001 records would be voided and solution reached by adding two columns. First column would read code (i.e. "X11") for High and largest date for one rec; and second would read count of high for one record. Thanx hope it makes sense

Comment: thanx, Im assuming that adding new column to the df pivot would be simpel as adding new_series.

Comment: Tell me exactly what you want to do. Since one result is index by rec and the other by rec and code, the merge of the two is not obvious. If you have the same index (rec for example), it's easy.

Comment: pivot is ok, added columns would be based on rec. "Count column" would be count of all High for rec (10001) , from my example table would be 2. "Code column" would represent code for High only but with largest date (from my table would be X11 and not X11.1). Thank you.

Comment: Code doesnt work with two High entries under same Rec

Comment: @pythonED I've just updated my answer, I hope this is the expected result. Next time, prepare thoroughly the question in order to avoir people that are trying to help you losing their (free) time.

Comment: X Thanx a lot, sorry on trouble, this works perfectly.